# How to open System > Administration?

Tags: system, system-settings

I'm new to Ubuntu and while browsing over forums I saw goto System > Administration and so on. So I wanna know how I can actually goto System, means where can I find System then Administration and so on?

Comment: what do you actually want to achieve through "Administrator"? Also, what version of Ubuntu are you using? Are you running Gnome shell? To find out, open terminal (Ctrl + Alt + T) and then type in `echo $DESKTOP_SESSION` and hit enter. Generally, system administration is through Applications>System tools in Ubuntu 11.10 with `gnome-panel`. You can also click your user name (top right corner) and get system settings.

Answer (score 2):

From comment:

> Actually I'm trying install my graphic driver and for this i need to goto 'System | Administration | Hardware Drivers' and I'm using latest version which is ubuntu 12.10

As of 12.10: see the Additional Drivers tab in the Software Sources menu.

[image]

In case of AMD you will see different drivers here.

You can get there from the normal places like Ubuntu Software Center (it is in the options at the top left)

Answer (score 0):

Click on the home/start button of your keyboard or on the icon on the side called as "dash home". It will present you with what is called as dash. It is like a search option. Type what ever you want to search in your system here. In your case type "System" in the search bar. It will show you all the applications documents etc having a word "system" in them. Select the required application and there you go.

PS : This solution works only you are in Unity. Not in a fallback/old version of gnome shell that is available through gnome-panel for 11.04 and above.

Comment: You might want to add that your answer works when you are in Unity. Not in a fallback/old version of gnome shell that is available through `gnome-panel` for `11.04` and above.

Comment: @drN actually I'm trying install my graphic driver and for this i need to goto 'System | Administration | Hardware Drivers' and I'm using latest version which is ubuntu 12.10

Comment: @dhruv Click your name (top right in case you use gnome-shell) system settings>hardware drivers

Comment: @dhruv so it does the trick for you?

Comment: If yes then please mark the answer as the right answer.

Comment: @drN well in system settings there no such thing hardware drivers. All i can see is different options like appearance, bluetooth, backup ,etc

Comment: You will see additional drivers in Hardware as seen here http://dl.dropbox.com/u/56860240/Screenshot%20from%202012-10-28%2021%3A49%3A50.png

Comment: The trials and tribulations of using Unity as against gnome 2 or below. I am seriously considering moving to Ubuntu 9 or below or slack from Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: No there is no such thing..

Comment: Type "system setting" in dash. Bdw u understand what dash is?

Comment: yes i know abt 'dash'..well i'm tryin to dis from da morning n its been jst two days i installed ubuntu.

Comment: Chill dude I am just trying to help you out :)

Comment: here a screenshot if it helps you figure out my case [link](http://imgur.com/Sg60h)

Comment: I would recommend that you google your problem or search for it on this site. I am sure you will get a proper reply on either of the two sites. Unfortunately I have my exams starting from tomorrow and can't help much right now.

Comment: okay now prb..thanxx..n bst of luck buddy

Comment: @dhruv problem solved?