# System Adminstration

Tags: system-settings, administration

I have lots of instructions for various things that tell me to choose the Administration function from my System menu. It doesn't exist. What should I do?

Comment: First of all, what exactly are the instructions you have? And which version of Ubuntu are you using. I don't remember having such a "System Menu" as from 11.10 or so...

Comment: My CUPS isn't working at all. When I troubleshoot it says "The CUPS print spooler does not appear to be running. To correct this, choose System->Adminstration->Services from the main menu and look for the 'cups' service." I have  Systems Settings window that I can open, in that window there is a section simply called System. However, in that section called System, there is no option for Administration.

Comment: The about this computer says I am running 16.04LTS, 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Modern Ubuntu distros does not support *System->Administration* tab. [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207718/how-to-open-system-administration) and [there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76018/how-to-open-system-administrator-menu) exist threads which proves answer to this problem.

If you want to start **cups** service, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

`sudo service cups start`